# Is possible install FFMPEG Linux 5.2 without root?

Tags: software-installation, webserver, ffmpeg, non-root-user

I want install FFMPEG to Linux 5.2 without access root, is possible?
I use a server to host a website. I have access only access to the directory `public_html` to host the website. 
To install FFMPEG is it necessary use the `/usr/bin` directory? Is it possible install FFMPEG on the directory `public_html`?

Comment: Where have you been stuck? Download the source, compile with "--prefix=/path/to/public_html/" and install.

Answer (score 1):

Without superuser access, you cannot use the package manager to install software packages.  However, if the system has compilers and the required libraries installed, you can download the source code and compile the software yourself, and curtail its installation to within your home directory tree.  Most source archives come with a `README`, `INSTALL`, and/or `COMPILING` file which will describe the process.

Comment: Just to mention: he can copy the files from the package directly to /path/to/public_html .

Comment: Unless they're dynamically linked against libraries not installed on the system.  What an HTTP server is expected to to with an executable other than serve it up for download, I am not going to even touch. (:

Comment: He can set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH easily and use any libraries unpacked from packages.

Comment: Things like `Gentoo Prefix` can be easier if one wants to bootstrap a working subsystem without superuser access. (Things do mess up if the only available working directory is located in a filesystem with `noexec`, though...)